# WordPress session problems

Tags: wordpress

I have found a bunch of articles talking about using sessions.
From what I have been able to find the best way is to add an init action.
I have been following this article
http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

But I must be missing something. every time I call the page with my plugin there is no session id.

Am I missing something?

thanks for any help

```php
add_action('init', 'my_GB_StartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'my_GB_myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'my_GB_myEndSession');
if (!function_exists('my_GB_StartSession')) {
    function my_GB_StartSession() {
        if(!session_id()) {
            errorLog("session starting\n");
            session_start();
        }
    }
}
function UnitNet_GB_myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors i your php error log? "errorLog("session starting\n");" shouldn't it be error_log('session starting\n'); ?

Comment: no i am not getting any errors. The errorLog is a function in my stuff and i get the session starting each time in my log file

Comment: Calling session_start will set the $_SESSION global, so if you call it before wp-settiings is run and register_globals is set you will lose your session variables.

Answer (score 0):

**try this and add to your theme's function.php :**

```php
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

**Now the session is yours to use as you wish in your code:**

```php
$_SESSION['myKey'] = "Some data I need later";

if(isset($_SESSION['myKey'])) {
    $value = $_SESSION['myKey'];
} else {
    $value = '';
}
```

**Or add this to wp-config.php before the wp-settings (e.g top of the wp-config.php)**

```php
if (!session_id())
    session_start();
```